# iOS 5 Style Switch Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying the iOS 5 Style Switch Control tutorial. For some reason the tutorial doesn't use the ON OFF labels for the state of the check box.

http://css3wizardry.com/2011/12/18/ios-5-style-switch-control/

Is there a way to have the switch control display ON or OFF? versus the line & circle?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide a link to the tutorial you're using, as there could be many different ones that teach the same thing.

Comment: Sorry about that, added: http://css3wizardry.com/2011/12/18/ios-5-style-switch-control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing, but play around with:

```
.switch > .thumb::after {
    content: "OFF";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

Just a matter of positioning the content.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a much better solution: http://ios-checkboxes.awardwinningfjords.com/